# Prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n ar^{i-1} =$ ${a\left({1 - r^n}\right)\over 1 - r}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

a and r are constants with r $\neq$ 1 and I have to use the Principle of Mathematical Induction to prove.

I'm at the point where I'm trying to show $$\sum_{i=1}^{n + 1} ar^{i-1} = {a\left({1 - r^{n+1}}\right)\over 1 - r}$$

So, I have $${a\left({1 - r^n}\right)\over 1 - r} + ar^{n+1-1}$$,

$${a\left({1 - r^n}\right)\over 1 - r} + ar^n$$

I think to solve this I can use a common denominator and do

$${a\left({1 - r^n}\right)\over 1 - r} + ar^n{\left(1-r\over 1-r\right)}$$

but, then I get $${a\over 1-r}$$ because the ${1-r}$ and $ar^n$ cancel out? So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r} + \frac{ar^n ( 1-r)}{1-r} = \frac{a - ar^n + ar^{n} - ar^{n+1}}{1-r}\\
= \frac{a-a r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: Thanks, AHusain ! I just could not see that and my first instinct was to just cancel top and bottom.